# Android Studio lists device as "???????????????? [null]"

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, unknown-device

I am an android developer working with my office mac. But now I want to migrate the projects to Ubuntu.

I installed Android studio and trying to run project on my device ASUS Zenfone 5 (Kitkat).

But the device list is showing as `?????????????????[null]`

I tried to run in Nexus 7, its working fine and no issues found.

Is there any issues in my device settings ? Or any settings change in my Android studio.. ?

[image]

Comment: Connect your device, then turn  USB debugging off and again on. Does this solution work?

Comment: @Dante there is no point in restarting the USB debugging if Ubuntu is preventing non-root access to the device.

Answer (score 3):

If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a `udev` rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the `ATTR{idVendor}` property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs, below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux: Log in as root and create this file:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC (to get your vendor ID use `lsusb` command with connected device). The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node. Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.

Now execute:

```
chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

The full solution is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html).